# TypeError: Cannot read property "price" from undefined in <eval> at line number

Tags: javascript

someone wrote this JS for me and it worked earlier but now it does not; I cannot get hold of that person so I am reaching out for assistance. I had spent numerous hours trying to correct this but I am not experienced enough with JS .

I am receiving this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property "price" from undefined in  at line number 67

```
// Create input variables
var orderItems = [];
var rowsArray = ${rows([]);object(of=json)};
var auxObj = {
'Lip Balm - Orange Coconut': ${lipBalmOrangeCoconut(0)},
'Lip Balm - Raspberry Vanilla': ${lipBalmRaspberryVanilla(0)},
'Bath Bomb - Assorted - 50 mg THC': ${bathBombAssorted50MgThc(0)},
'Buddha Buddha - 200 mg THC': ${buddhaBuddha200MgThc(0)},
'Top Lemon Balm Salve': ${topLemonBalmSalve(0)},
'Buddha Bar - 300 mg THC': ${buddhaBar300MgThc(0)},
'BC Skunk - Hybrid': ${bcSkunkHybrid(0)},
'Blue King - Hybrid': ${blueKingHybrid(0)},
'CBD Treat - Hybrid': ${cbdTreatHybrid(0)},
'Dr. Krippling - Indica': ${drKripplingIndica(0)},
"God's Blue Cough - Hybrid": ${godsBlueCoughHybrid(0)},
'Island Sweet Skunk - Sativa': ${islandSweetSkunkSativa(0)},
'Lemon Sour Diesel - Hybrid': ${lemonSourDieselHybrid(0)},
'MI-O - Sativa': ${mioSativa(0)},
'OG Kush - Hybrid': ${ogKushHybrid(0)},
'Strawberry Skunk - Hybrid': ${strawberrySkunkHybrid(0)},
'Bubble Hash ': ${bubbleHash(0)},
'CBD - 2 capsules per package': ${cbd2CapsulesPerPackage(0)},
'CBD - 30 capsules per bottle': ${cbd30CapsulesPerBottle(0)},
'CBD Phoenix Tears ': ${cbdPhoenixTears(0)},
'THC Phoenix Tears ': ${thcPhoenixTears(0)},
'THC grape seed oil (indica) 900 mg / 30 ml': 
${thcGrapeSeedOilindica900Mg30Ml(0)},
'THC grape seed oil (sativa) 900 mg / 30 ml': 
${thcGrapeSeedOilsativa900Mg30Ml(0)},
'1:1 THC:CBD grape seed oil 200 mg / 30 ml': 
${11ThccbdGrapeSeedOil200Mg30Ml(0)},
'CBD grape seed oil 150 mg / 30 ml': ${cbdGrapeSeedOil150Mg30Ml(0)},
'Chocolate Chip Cookie - 15 mg THC': ${chocolateChipCookie15MgThc(0)},
'Ginger Chew Cookie - 30 mg THC': ${gingerChewCookie30MgThc(0)},
'Red Licorice Bites - 125 mg THC': ${redLicoriceBites125MgThc(0)},
'Double Dose Peanut Butter Cup - 200 mg THC': 
${doubleDosePeanutButterCup200MgThc(0)},
'Cherry - 125 mg THC (hybrid)': ${cherry125MgThchybrid(0)},
'Rootbeer - 125 mg THC (sativa)': ${rootbeer125MgThcsativa(0)},
'Watermelon - 125 mg THC (hybrid)': ${watermelon125MgThchybrid(0)},
'Cherry - 120 mg (indica)': ${cherry120Mgindica(0)},
'Blue Raspberry - 120 mg (indica)': ${blueRaspberry120Mgindica(0)},
'Peach  - 120 mg (sativa)': ${peach120Mgsativa(0)},
'Strawberry Banana - 120 mg (sativa)': ${strawberryBanana120Mgsativa(0)},
'Lollipops - Assorted Flavors - 150 mg THC': 
${lollipopsAssortedFlavors150MgThc(0)},
'Cotton Candy - Original - 180 mg THC': ${cottonCandyOriginal180MgThc(0)},
'Cotton Candy - Tutti Fruitti - 180 mg THC': 
${cottonCandyTuttiFruitti180MgThc(0)},
'Cranberry Ice Tea Apothecary - 60 mg THC': 
${cranberryIceTeaApothecary60MgThc(0)},
'Lemon Ice Tea Apothecary - 60 mg THC': ${lemonIceTeaApothecary60MgThc(0)},
'Mango Ice Tea Apothecary - 60 mg THC': ${mangoIceTeaApothecary60MgThc(0)},
'Peach Ice Tea Apothecary - 60 mg THC': ${peachIceTeaApothecary60MgThc(0)},
'Coconut Oil - 500 mg THC': ${coconutOil500MgThc(0)},
'Olive Oil - 400 mg THC': ${oliveOil400MgThc(0)},
'House Strain - Hybrid': ${houseStrainHybrid(0)},
};

// Create a "lookup table" for stock nr. and price
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0, len = rowsArray.length; i < len; i++) {
lookup[rowsArray[i].formName] = rowsArray[i];
}

var amount = 0,
subtotal = 0,
tax = 0,
shipping = 20,
total = 0;

for (var key in auxObj) {
if (auxObj[key] !== 0) {
    amount = auxObj[key] * lookup[key].price;
    orderItems.push({
        'value': auxObj[key],
        'name': key,
        'stock': lookup[key].stock,
        'price': lookup[key].price,
        'amount': amount
    });
    subtotal += amount;
}
}
tax = subtotal * 0.05;
total = subtotal + tax + shipping;


// Return output variables
var result = {
'orderItems' : orderItems,
'subtotal': subtotal,
'tax': tax,
'total': total
};
result;
```

Line 67 'price' has the error.
I don't know if this amount of code is enough, if you need the full code then please ask.
I don't know why the error is happening (keep in mind I'm not exp. w/JS) and how to fix it to run.

Comment: What does lookup look like?

Comment: So lookup[key] is undefined...

Comment: Please consider clarifying the question. Line 67 of the posted code is `subtotal = 0`. Also unclear is whether this is all inside a string template.

Comment: amount = auxObj[key] * lookup[key].price;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is being caused because `lookup` does not have a property named `key`, therefore `lookup[key]` is undefined. Whenever a property does not exist in an object (e.g. `lookup[key]` or lookup.mykey) it will be `undefined` in JavaScript.

As you haven't suggested how to handle non-existent items in your `lookup` object I would suggest something similar to the following to fix your issue:

```
    var lookupItem = lookup[key];

    orderItems.push({
        'value': auxObj[key],
        'name': key,
        'stock': lookupItem ? lookupItem.stock : 0, 
        // If the lookup item exists return the stock value, otherwise return 0. In JavaScript, all objects are truthy in an boolean expression if they are defined and not null, otherwise falsy.
        'price': lookupItem ? lookupItem.price : 0,
        'amount': amount
    });
```

Comment: I think I did something wrong, it's still not processing and so maybe I placed it somewhere in error?

Comment: The execution failed! TypeError: Cannot read property "price" from undefined in <eval> at line number 84

Answer (score 0):

I think the price index in the lookup object is undefined. Try checking for the index before you access it in the object.

```
var price, stock;
for (var key in auxObj) {
    if (auxObj[key] !== 0) {

        price = ( typeof lookup[key].price !== 'undefined' ? lookup[key].price : 0 );

        stock = ( typeof lookup[key].stock !== 'undefined' ? lookup[key].stock : 'Not in stock' );

        amount = auxObj[key] * lookup[key].price;
        orderItems.push({
             'value': auxObj[key],
             'name': key,
             'stock': lookup[key].stock,
             'price': lookup[key].price,
             'amount': amount
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: I think I did something wrong here too, it's still not processing and so maybe I placed it somewhere in error?

Comment: The execution failed! ReferenceError: "lookup" is not defined in <eval> at line number 65